# Subscript indices must be real positive integers or logicals

Tags: octave, gradient-descent

```
function [theta, J_history] = gradientDescent(X, y, theta, alpha, num_iters)
%GRADIENTDESCENT Performs gradient descent to learn theta
%   theta = GRADIENTDESENT(X, y, theta, alpha, num_iters) updates theta by 
%   taking num_iters gradient steps with learning rate alpha

% Initialize some useful values  
m = length(y); % number of training examples
J_history = zeros(num_iters, 1);

for iter = 1:num_iters

% ====================== YOUR CODE HERE ======================
% Instructions: Perform a single gradient step on the parameter vector
%               theta. 
%
% Hint: While debugging, it can be useful to print out the values
%       of the cost function (computeCost) and gradient here.
%

    hypothesis = x*theta;
    theta_0 = theta(1) - alpha(1/m)*sum((hypothesis-y)*x);
    theta_1 = theta(2) - alpha(1/m)*sum((hypothesis-y)*x);
    theta(1) = theta_0;
    theta(2) = theta_1;








% ============================================================

% Save the cost J in every iteration    
    J_history(iter) = computeCost(X, y, theta);

end

end
```

I keep getting this error

```
error: gradientDescent: subscript indices must be either positive integers less than 2^31 or logicals
```

on this line right in-between the first theta and =

```
theta_0 = theta(1) - alpha(1/m)*sum((hypothesis-y)*x);
```

I'm very new to octave so please go easy on me, and
thank you in advance.
This is from the coursera course on Machine Learning from Week 2

Comment: Iter-1 starts at 1-1=0, but octave is 1-based (arrays start at 1)

Comment: even when i do that it still gives an error

Comment: I don't think you need to be subsetting by `iter` in `theta(iter-1)` and `X(iter,2)` ? The previous iteration is already stored in `theta`, and you're changing `theta` on each iteration?

Comment: I changed my code because in all honesty i don't know what i was doing last time. And this time I still get the same error on the same place

Comment: `alpha(1/m)` or perhaps `alpha * (1/m)`?

Comment: I took this course about 6 months ago and also seem to remember that you had to be careful with transposing your matrices/vectors too, so that the multiplications make sense

Comment: yea i see what your saying I'm so used to pythons parenthesis multiplication it kinda stuck, thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

99% sure your error is on the line pointed out by topsig, where you have `alpha(1/m)`

it would help if you gave an example of input values to your function and what you hoped to see as an output, but I'm assuming from your comment

`%  taking num_iters gradient steps with learning rate alpha`

that `alpha` is a constant, not a function.  as such, you have the line `alpha(1/m)` without any operator in between. octave sees this as you indexing `alpha` with the value of `1/m`.

i.e., if you had an array

```
x = [3 4 5]
x*(2) = [6 8 10]  %% two times each element in the array
x(2) = [4]  %% second element in the array
```

what you did doesn't seem to make sense, as 'm = length(y)' which will output a scalar,  so

```
x = [3 4 5]; m = 3;
x*(1/m) = x*(1/3) = [1 1.3333 1.6666]  %% element / 3
x(1/m) = ___error___  %% the 1/3 element in the array makes no sense
```

note that for certain errors it always indicates that the location of the error is at the assignment operator (the equal sign at the start of the line). if it points there, you usually have to look elsewhere in the line for the actual error. here, it was yelling at you for trying to apply a non-integer subscript `(1/m)`

Comment: Yea I see what happened, I was expecting it to go through with multiplication using only parenthesis instead of a multiplication sign